# drag and drop functionality enhancement in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I know by the question, you will say Drag and Drop Functionality is already avaliable, Yes that is true,

I am trying to add the Drag and Drop functionality to the showFilters Option which comes up in the Angular JS ng-Grid, I am providing an Image here, I am working with same examples, so do not have much code to share, almost all is same as per examples on the ng-grid on angular JS website.

the Image below, where i am trying the Drag and Drop functionality inside that pane only.

[image: The Help where it is required]

Comment: Give us some code what you've tried so far, do you realy expect that we go to the angularJS website, look for the example code and after that code it for you?

Comment: if that is the case, i am adding the pasbin code here so you can see, the reason i wanna add to pastebin is because i cannot add here, i do not how to add in comment box, it will make it messy

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AvdSAx9z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the Class to handle the Dragging of the components and work flawlessly. Just ad the class of the jquery UI draggable and its done